# Unit testing in Angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

This is my first time testing in Angular and my first day at a new job. I am trying to write a test to see that the MainCtrl.lables contains something (or ideally get the values from dataRepository)
Does anyone know how to do this or know any good resources for angular testing for controllers that require a service? Im having trouble finding good information for how to use mocks.

MainCtrl.js

```
var app = angular.module("ChartApp", ["chart.js"]);

    app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope",
      function ($scope, dataRepository) {
          $scope.labels = dataRepository.labels;
          $scope.data = dataRepository.data;
          $scope.type = dataRepository.type;
          $scope.title = dataRepository.title;
      }
    ]);
```

DataSrv.js

```
angular.module("ChartApp")
    .factory('dataRepository', function () {
        return { 
            labels: ["Reading", "Coding", "Thinking About Coding", "Reddit", "StackOverflow"],
            data: [500, 300, 300, 40, 220],
            type: 'PolarArea',
            title: "Angular Chart Expriment"
        };
    });
```

MainCtrlSpec.js

```
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/angular/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/angular/angular-mocks.js" />
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/chartjs/Chart.js" />
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/angular-chart.js-master/dist/angular-chart.js" />
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/controller/main-controller.js" />
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/service/data-service.js" />
/// <reference path="../../libs/jasmine/jasmine.js" />

describe("Controller: MainCtrl", function () {
    beforeEach(module("ChartApp"));

    var ctrl, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
        scope = {};
        ctrl = $controller("MainCtrl" });
    }));

    it("should have scope defined", function () {
        expect(MainCtrl.lables).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the service then you should write a test for that service, not for the controller. But if you want to test it in the controller you can do it like so:

```
describe('Controller: NewCtrl', function () {
var NewCtrl, scope;
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_myService_, $controller, $injector, $rootScope) {
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ...
        NewCtrl = $controller('NewCtrl', {
                    $scope: scope, // here you specify the custom mocked value you wish to set for the injected service
        });
    ...

  });
 it('should have labels defined', function(){
         expect(scope.labels).toBeDefined();
        });
    ...
    });
```

And in your controller, you would have to do something like:

`$scope.labels = dataRepository.labels;`

I also suggest using [Karma runner](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) since it has lots of great addons like:

1. [karma-coverage](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage)
2. [karma-phantomjs launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher)

And also, if you're using a modern IDE it will probably integrate well with your workflow ;)
A very good resource to get started with unit testing controller is **[this one](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/13/how-to-unit-test-controllers-in-angularjs-without-setting-your-hair-on-fire/)** since it also dives into [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) which is a very important tool when using `$resource` or `$http` in your code.